# Privacy message shown during In-App Purchases in iTunes

Tags: itunes

I am struggling to get our iPhone client into the App Store, and have been told that we have to add in-app purchases. But I have a couple of questions.

So far everything looks OK in the sandbox, except that I sometimes get an alert that looks like this:

**Share your Information?**

The publisher of Philip Sheard would like your name, email and postcode for use in accordance with their privacy policy.

[Environment: Sandbox]

**Don't Allow | Allow**

Now it should not be my name of course, or even the name of my company, but the name of the application. And we only really need the email address, not the name or the postcode. Is there any way I can fix this?

Also we would hope to receive an email message from iTunes whenever a purchase is made, which would hopefully include at least the email address of the purchaser. I am not getting this at the moment, but is that because I am testing it in the sandbox environment? Sorry for asking such a trivial question, but no one in our company has any experience with Apple culture.

Answer (score 0):

the name is likely coming from your contract somewhere. but as for the email for each time a purchase is made is pointless, your app is handling the in-app buy, if its successful your own app could send an email or track the sale live however you wish. note in general its better to control such things on your end anyways.